# C# Generic Method with generic parameter whose type is different than that of the one used on the class

Tags: c#, generics, implicit-conversion

I have a generic base to represent some kind of numbers. I need to override some implicit conversions to built-in types (like short, ushort, int, uint, etc...). One possible way is to override every possible type as seen in the code below:

```
public class MyBaseClass<T> 
     where T : struct, IComparable, IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>
{
     private T _value;

     public MyBaseClass(T value)
     {
        _value = value;
     }

     // Implicit Conversions
     static public implicit operator MyBaseClass<T>(Int16 value) 
            => new MyBaseClass<T>((dynamic)value);

     static public implicit operator MyBaseClass<T>(UInt16 value) 
            => new MyBaseClass<T>((dynamic)value);

     static public implicit operator MyBaseClass<T>(Int32 value) 
            => new MyBaseClass<T>((dynamic)value);

     // ... some more implicit conversions...
}
```

The question is: Instead of having to do for every possible option, is there a way to do it only once with something like the below:

```
static public implicit operator MyBaseClass<T>(U value) where U: struct 
          => new MyBaseClass<T>((dynamic)value);
```

I tried with and without the part *where T : struct* but with no prevail.

Any idea?

**PS: The above code is a *.NET Core* C# on *Mac* using *Visual Studio Code*.**

Comment: Just replace U with T and remove "where" constraint and "(dynamic)". It will work fine

Comment: You cannot do it this way, because operators do not support generic parameters.